# No crawled properties for modern site in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

I have the following issue: my Custom Site Columns are not appearing  as Crawled or Managed Properties in SharePoint Online Modern Experience i.e. Communication and Team Site.

Steps Followed:-

Created Communication or Team Site in SharePoint Online
Created one site column.
Created custom list and added custom site column.
Activated all search related feature at Site & Web Level.
Applied Re-Index entire site as well as custom list and wait for couple of hours.

As I navigate to Search Schema -> Search for custom site column under Managed & Crawled Property.  It doesn’t appear, even I tried with prefix ows_ also.

Any thoughts please ??

(also asked but not answered on https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/SharePoint-Online-Modern-Experience-Search-Custom-Site-Column-to/td-p/214441)

Answer (score 0):

There is an outage at the moment with office 365 SharePoint online search schema.

Check the service health advisory dashboard